# Qt Custom User Theming

Tags: css, qt

I am trying to set up a method for theming with external files. Currently, I have a file being read and put into a QString, then being placed inside of "qApp->setStyleSheet(string);, this seems to work,however, when i color the background of a button it doesn't seem to work. The same css works directly inside of qt designer too.

Function:

```
void SeniorProject::themer(QString theme_name)
{
    qDebug() << theme_name;
    QString file = QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath()
            + "/themes/" + "default" + "/theme.style";
    qDebug() << "file = " + file;
    QFile themeFile(file);
    QString themeStyle;
    if (themeFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
    {
        QTextStream in (&themeFile);
        themeStyle = in.readAll();
        themeFile.close();
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug() << "error";
    }
    qApp->setStyleSheet(themeStyle);
    update();
}
```

CSS File

```
QPushButton#exit {
    color: rgb(220, 0, 0);
    border: none;
    outline: none;
}
QPushButton#exit:hover {
    color: rgb(255, 8, 0);
}
QPushButton#exit:Pressed {
    color: rgb(150, 0, 0);
}


QFrame#mainbox QPushButton {
    background: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1, stop: 0 rgba(122,188,255,1), stop: 0.44 rgba(96,171,248,1), stop: 1 rgba(64,150,238,1));
    border: .1px outset rgb(122, 188, 255);
    border-radius:4px;
}
QFrame#mainbox QPushButton:hover {
    background: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1, stop: 0 rgba(147,201,255,1), stop: 0.44 rgba(133,190,247,1), stop: 1 rgba(90,163,237,1));
    border: .1px outset rgb(122, 188, 255);
    border-radius:4px;
}
QFrame#mainbox QPushButton:pressed {
    background: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1, stop: 0 rgba(84,169,255,1), stop: 0.44 rgba(66,155,244,1), stop: 1 rgba(45,141,237,1));
    border: .1px outset  rgb(122, 188, 255);
    border-radius:4px;
}
```

The background in the QPushButtons is my currently problem, the stylesheet loads correctly and updates (I can tell because the borders on the buttons actually change to what I want), but the background does not seem to be working. Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Comment: What background do you expect with full transparency (1 of 255)? Try `rgba(96,171,248,255)`

Comment: @DmitrySazonov, it was genereated by qt creator's gradients. I set it to 255, however and the problem still persists. Having the transparency at 1 and styling it directly in creator works with 1 too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out why the background was not working. If you have the background previously set of the entire widget that is the parent of the item you are trying to style through QT Designer will not be able to have a background when it is not set with QT Designer.